# Fubini's Theorem on Ito's integral?

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

> It is well known that Fubini's Theorem allows us to swap two interated integrals. 
>   In stochastic calculus, Fubini's Theorem (under certain conditions) ensures that 
>   $$\mathbb{E}\int_0^t g(W_s) ds = \int_0^t \mathbb{E}g(W_s) ds$$
>   for some function $g$ and $W_s$ is a Brownian motion.

Is it possible to apply Fubini's Theorem to Ito's integral?
More precisely,

> Do we have 
>   $$\mathbb{E}\int_0^t g(W_s) dW_s = \int_0^t\mathbb{E} g(W_s) dW_s?$$

Comment: The left hand side is a real number. The right hand side is a random variable. Fubini’s theorem works on stochastic integrals as well but not in the way you wrote. You can just google to see how it works

Comment: Indeed, for reasonably nice $g$ (e.g. bounded), $\int_0^t g(W_s)\,dW_s$ is a martingale and so its expectation is just zero.

Comment: @Calculon Perhaps you can provide an accurate fubini Theorem for stochastic integral and post it as an answer?

Comment: @Idonknow I will take a look

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will mention a Fubini-type theorem for double integrals involving a stochastic integral and a Lebesgue integral. But keep in mind that there are results for double stochastic integrals as well.

Let $g: X\times[0,\infty)\times\Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a parametrized stochastic process with the parameter taking values in $X$ and $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure on a $\sigma$-algebra defined on this space. $g$ satisfies certain measurability properties on the triple product $\sigma$-algebra, which I won't get into as this is a very technical area.

> > Suppose that 
> >     $$\int_X\left(\int_0^t \lvert g(x, s, \omega)\rvert^2ds\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}d\mu(x) < \infty$$
> >     Then,
> >     $$\int_X\int_0^t g(x, s)dW_sd\mu(x) = \int_0^t \int_Xg(x, s)d\mu(x)dW_s$$

The example you gave does not fit into this framework as the outer integral on the left hand side is on $\Omega$, not a separate parameter space. You cannot treat it as a parameter space as it is coupled to the inner integral. I don't see how you can exchange two integrals that take place on the same domain in different ways. Well, technically the stochastic integral is on $[0,t]$ but it is defined using convergence in $\Omega$.

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for this? Also, what is the condition (after "Suppose that")? Is it almost surely?

Comment: @jacques: maybe Theorem IV.64,65 on Protter's Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations are what you are looking for.